# Why assumptions of exponential family on the complete conditionals imply a conjugacy relationship on other variables

Tags: machine-learning, variational-bayes

I am reading the Stochastic Variational Inference [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.7051). Basically it first assumes that the joint distribution factorizes into a global term and a product of local terms.
$$p(x, z, \beta | \alpha) = p(\beta | \alpha) \prod_{n=1}^N p(x_n, z_n | \beta)$$
It also assumes that the complete conditionals are in the exponential family.(formula (2) (3) in the paper)
$$p(\beta | x, z, \alpha) = h(\beta) \exp \{ \eta_g(x, z, \alpha)^\top t(\beta) - a_g(\eta_g(x, z, \alpha))\}$$
and
$$p(z_{nj} | x_n, z_{n, -j}, \beta) = h(z_{nj}) \exp \{ \eta_\ell (x_n, z_{n, -j}, \beta)^\top t(z_{nj}) - a_\ell(\eta_\ell(x_n, z_{n, -j}, \beta))\}$$
My question is that how these assumptions imply that the distribution of $x_n, z_n$ given $\beta$ and the prior distribution $p(\beta)$ are also in the exponential family(formula (4) (5))?